# Kubuntu 16.04 - Wireless card is crashing and cannot be restored

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, intel-wireless, xps

Hardware: Dell XPS 13 9350
Wireless Card: Intel 7265 11ac Wireless Card with Bluetooth 4.0

Symptoms: At seemingly random times, the network will drop and the wireless interface seems to disappear. I have run some diagnostics the output of which is below:

Any help appreciated - I currently have to reboot the machine when this occurs in order to re-enable the wireless.

**Output when working fine:**

```
Kernel Version:
uname -r
4.4.0-22-generic

Network Card:
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 59
       serial: 10:02:b5:34:d2:3f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=192.168.1.164 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:284 memory:dc200000-dc201fff

Network Config:
iwconfig
docker0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp58s0   IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"EE-xs954q"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: C4:E9:84:80:6C:00   
          Bit Rate=300 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:74   Missed beacon:0

sudo ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

Can Scan?
sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.


Module Conf:
ls -aFC /etc/modprobe.d
./           blacklist-framebuffer.conf   fbdev-blacklist.conf
../          blacklist-modem.conf         iwlwifi.conf
alsa-base.conf       blacklist-oss.conf@          mlx4.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf   blacklist-rare-network.conf  vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
blacklist.conf       blacklist-watchdog.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf  dkms.conf

Wireless Module:
iwlmvm                311296  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm

NetworkManager State:
cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

NetworkManager Status:
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager status
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-05-21 12:03:20 BST; 2min 38s ago
 Main PID: 1011 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 512)
   Memory: 12.6M
      CPU: 792ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─1011 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           ├─1522 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-wlp58s0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-1aa3bca2-2563-4fcb-949d-5dd19db09ac4-wlp58s0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlp58s0.conf wlp58s0
           └─1533 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d

May 21 12:03:24 ant-XPS-13-9350 dnsmasq[1533]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
May 21 12:03:24 ant-XPS-13-9350 dnsmasq[1533]: DBus support enabled: connected to system bus
May 21 12:03:24 ant-XPS-13-9350 dnsmasq[1533]: warning: no upstream servers configured
May 21 12:03:24 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[1011]: <info>  [1463828604.7731] device (wlp58s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
May 21 12:03:24 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[1011]: <info>  [1463828604.7746] dnsmasq[0x26f2440]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.31
May 21 12:03:24 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[1011]: <info>  [1463828604.7747] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
May 21 12:03:24 ant-XPS-13-9350 dnsmasq[1533]: setting upstream servers from DBus
May 21 12:03:24 ant-XPS-13-9350 dnsmasq[1533]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
May 21 12:03:30 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[1011]: <info>  [1463828610.9813] WiFi hardware radio set enabled
May 21 12:03:30 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[1011]: <info>  [1463828610.9814] WWAN hardware radio set enabled

Wireless State:
sudo rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Try:
 sudo rfkill unblock all
 sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
 http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/wireless-became-disabled-how-do-i-enable-858357/
Also try:
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo rfkill event
```

**Output when Network disappears:**

```
Kernel Version:
uname -r
4.4.0-22-generic

Network Card:
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       version: 59
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc200000-dc201fff

Network Config:
iwconfig
docker0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

sudo ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

Can Scan?
sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.


Module Conf:
ls -aFC /etc/modprobe.d
./           blacklist-framebuffer.conf   fbdev-blacklist.conf
../          blacklist-modem.conf         iwlwifi.conf
alsa-base.conf       blacklist-oss.conf@          mlx4.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf   blacklist-rare-network.conf  vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
blacklist.conf       blacklist-watchdog.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf  dkms.conf

Wireless Module:
iwlmvm                311296  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm

NetworkManager State:
cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

NetworkManager Status:
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager status
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-05-21 11:20:00 BST; 31min ago
 Main PID: 8688 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 512)
   Memory: 13.1M
      CPU: 1.057s
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─1506 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
           └─8688 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

May 21 11:20:00 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <info>  [1463826000.9897] device (docker0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
May 21 11:20:00 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <info>  [1463826000.9900] device (docker0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
May 21 11:20:00 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <info>  [1463826000.9901] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
May 21 11:20:01 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <info>  [1463826001.0022] device (docker0): Activation: successful, device activated.
May 21 11:20:01 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <info>  [1463826001.0029] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
May 21 11:20:01 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <info>  [1463826001.0033] ModemManager available in the bus
May 21 11:20:01 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <info>  [1463826001.0081] ofono is now available
May 21 11:20:01 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <warn>  [1463826001.0121] failed to enumerate oFono devices: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
May 21 11:20:11 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <info>  [1463826011.3478] WiFi hardware radio set enabled
May 21 11:20:11 ant-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[8688]: <info>  [1463826011.3480] WWAN hardware radio set enabled

Wireless State:
sudo rfkill list all
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Try: 
sudo rfkill unblock all 
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/wireless-became-disabled-how-do-i-enable-858357/

Also try:
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo rfkill event
```

Comment: Note - rfkill list all does not show the wifi device after the "crash"

Comment: I noticed it happens with me when I use the hardware key to close the wireless.

Comment: Don't know if this is really an "answer", but I encountered this problem with my Dell Latitude 5285 when installing Ubuntu 16.04.1. However, installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 resolved my issue. Smells like a driver compatibility issue that Xenial release 3 got right.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script in the end which reloaded the wifi drivers:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "-r" ]
then
    sudo rm -rf /lib/firmware/ath10k
    sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
fi

sudo modprobe ath10k_core 
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Actually, this script was for my new Dell which had the same issue, but a different wireless card. There was an easier fix for the old machine with the Intel card which just used nmcli to restart the wifi device. Something like this IIRC:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
nmcli radio wifi on
```

However, an update about 6 weeks or so ago seems to have fixed the issue on both machines. Thought I'd leave this in casse anyone has similar issues.